# firebase timestamps not serverside created

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I have a chat app in react native using firebase and it is crucial to me that the timestamps are all synchronised and created serversided, not from the client. Clients can have different times depending on the settings on the mobile phone.

I tried out following function to prove my point:

```
const comparetimes = async () => {
        const timezone1  = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now();
        const timezone2 = (firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()).toMillis();
        const timezone3 = Date.now();

        console.log(timezone1);
        console.log(timezone2);
        console.log(timezone3)


    }
```

What shocked me is the result of this function:

```
{"nanoseconds": 79000000, "seconds": 1641054839}
1641054839080
1641054839080
```

Apperently the firebase timestamp is the exact same as `Date.now()` which is a direct timestamp taken from the mobile phone, and therefore unaccurate.

What can I do to have timestamps **not** created by the client but by the server, in this example firebase? Do I need to checkout some APIs or is there something I miss here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `Timestamp.now()`, it really is just taking the timestamp on the client device.  That's expected.

Read the [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#field-values) on how to use server timestamps.  You must use the token value returned by `firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` in order to tell Firestore to use the current moment in time as the request reaches the server.

> When storing timestamps, it is recommended you use the serverTimestamp
> static method on the FieldValue class. When written to the database,
> the Firebase servers will write a new timestamp based on their time,
> rather than the clients. This helps resolve any data consistency
> issues with different client timezones:
>
> ```
> firestore().doc('users/ABC').update({
>   createdAt: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
> });
> ```

Also read:

- https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-secrets-of-firestore-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-revealed-29dd7a38a82b

Comment: Fixed it for me. Exchanged local timestamps which were like `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()` with `firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`, stored them in firestore and retrieved them in my app and now it works perfectly.